# Fetching Date Data from DB returns undefined or null

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongodb, express, momentjs

I am willing to pass the dates data from my MongoDB to the antD Date Picker as disabled dates but after fetching the data of date, I get either undefined or null.
What is the approach here?
Below can be seen that my DB has date as a string converted to ISOString, but on fetching it via MongoDB, I get either undefined or null.
My main logic was to pull this date info as response.data.data in frontend after page-loading and passing this data to a useState of setUnavailable date and then assigning this setState to the disableddate function to get a boolean.

```
Here is my code:
The data in my DB is:

`{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "63690afb0623f513b3f22704"
  },
  "userId": "63614c627330d358d7ceff2d",
  "name": "SampleName",
  "title": "Doctor",
  "type": "Lab Consultation",
  "description": "Help Me Please",
  "timings": "2022-11-07T06:00:00.000Z",
  "date": "2022-11-15T00:00:00.000Z",
  "status": "pending",
  "createdAt": {
    "$date": {
      "$numberLong": "1667828475559"
    }
  },
  "updatedAt": {
    "$date": {
      "$numberLong": "1667828475559"
    }
  },
  "__v": 0
}
`
Schema:


`const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const consultationSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    createdBy: {
      type: mongoose.ObjectId,
      ref: "userModel",
    },
    userId: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    name: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    title: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    type: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    description: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    timings: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    date: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    status: {
      type: String,
      required: false,
      default: "pending",
    },
  },
  {
    timestamps: true,
  }
);

const consultationModel = mongoose.model("consultations", consultationSchema);

module.exports = consultationModel;
`
Router Get Data:

`router.get("/get-all-dates", authMiddleware, async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const consultation = await Consultation.find({
      date: { $gte: "2022-11-11T00:00:00.000Z" },
    });
    const dates = consultation.date;
    res.status(200).send({
      message: "All Dates Fetched Successfully",
      success: true,
      data: dates,
    });
    console.log(dates);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    res.status(500).send({
      message: "Fetching Dates Failed",
      success: false,
      error,
    });
  }
});
`
API Call in React:

 `const getDateData = async () => {
    try {
      dispatch(showLoading());
      const response = await axios.get("/api/user/get-all-dates", {
        headers: {
          Authorization: "Bearer " + localStorage.getItem("token"),
        },
      });
      dispatch(hideLoading());
      if (response.data.success) {
        setUnavailableDates(response.data.data);
        console.log(response.data.data);
        console.log(setUnavailableDates);
      }
    } catch (error) {
      dispatch(hideLoading());
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    getDateData();
  }, []);
  const disabledDate = (current) => {
    // How to pass the dates fecthed from DB here? Direct with setUnavailableDates?
    return current && current < moment().endOf("day");
  };
`
The output in network is this:

`{
    "message": "All Dates Fetched Successfully",
    "success": true
}`

The output in console is: undefined
```